# How do I keep my flash light code running while the app is put into background?

Tags: avcapturedevice, ios-background-mode

```
Button(action: {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        self.lightOn.toggle()
        
        let cam = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
        
        try? cam?.lockForConfiguration()
        
        if (cam?.torchMode == AVCaptureDevice.TorchMode.on) {
            cam?.torchMode = AVCaptureDevice.TorchMode.off
        }
        else if value == 0.0 {
            do {
                try cam?.setTorchModeOn(level: 0.05)
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        else  {
            do {
                try cam?.setTorchModeOn(level: value)
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        
        cam?.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
})
```

I've tried `gos:.userInteractive`, `userInitiated`, `utilities` and `background` but it doesn't seems to work. Anyone can let me know what went wrong?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with starting it on a certain thread. It's a system limitation. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32137434/560942

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the info. It helps a lot! 